# Getting color names from color picker

Tags: software-recommendation, colors

I am partially red-green color blind and would like to use a color picker to tell me what color things on my screen are. I recognize that utilities exist, such as gpick, grabc, gcolor2 that provide me with RGB or hex values. However, what I really want is for it to tell me that the color that I am looking at is "Red" or "OrangeRed" or some other name that I can relate to. A windows utility that does this is "What Color." Is there a linux equivalent or workaround? Like maybe I could pipe the output of gpick through some program that translates the hex to some English name for the color? Thanks!

Comment: If there is none... here is the list of colors imagemagick uses with their name: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php (possible method: toss those in a text file and do a grep with the result from gpick).

Comment: What about http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching through the repository I found `colorname` that seems to do what you want.

```
sudo apt-get install colorname
```

Using the eyedropper select a color then click `Execute` at the bottom, and it attempts to find the closest match from several color databases (Gimp, Wikipedia, X11).

Answer (score 2):

In 2021, `GPick` can tell you which color name is closest to the picked color.
In addition, this program has extensive functionality for building a color scheme, choosing a palette for a site, mixing colors, etc.
[image: GPick can tell the color name]

Comment: Gpick (0.2.6rc1) on Ubuntu 20.04.3 does not provide me color names. Should I add a color dictionary (Edit > Color Dictionaries...)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a command-line tool that does exactly that: [Cict](https://github.com/kallaballa/Cict)

Example:

```
$ ./cict 000081
1   #000080 navyblue
```

As you can see, you simple pass a 24-bit hex-value to cict and it reports the distance to the color found (1 in this case), the value of the actual color (#000080) and the name (navyblue).

Answer (score 0):

If your able to use gpick and color name is not generated
download this https://github.com/kallaballa/Cict/blob/master/colordict.txt

Import it
Edit >> Color Dictionaries..