# Color picker doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, colors, wayland

Gpick (0.2.6) is not working anymore on my computer (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS). When I click on "Pick color", I do not see the display around my mouse in the small box where it should be magnified. This box stays gray. When I pick a color (by pressing the space bar) it is always black (#000000).

I have downloaded Pick (2.0.2) but it does not work either.

I have also noticed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474056/getting-color-names-from-color-picker) that Gpick should be able to provide color name but it never worked on my computer. Under Edit>Color dictionaries, it seems that we can add a color dictionary file. Do you know how it works?

Many thanks for your help!

EDIT: I'm running wayland.

```
~$ env|grep XDG|grep -e XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP -e XDG_SESSION_TYPE
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
```

Comment: Which desktop environment are you running? Are you running x or wayland? Please run the following command line and post the result: `env|grep XDG|grep -e XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP -e XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

Comment: I'm running wayland. Please see the result of the command line above.

Comment: I suspect that Gpick does not work in Wayland. You can test that by switching to x11 on the log in screen (the round icon at the bottom right corner).

Comment: Thanks! I've switched to x11 and it works better. Now the correct color is picked but I don't see the magnified display in the small box of the app...

Comment: You are welcome @TVG :-) It happens that apps for graphics do not work exactly like before in new versions of the desktop environment. Sometimes it is improved, sometimes there is a regression. If you think it is an important regression, please create a bug report at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a dialogue via comments, we found out that the colour picker Gpick (0.2.6)

- does not work in Wayland
- works in x11 (but with a regression: the magnified display in the small box of the app is no longer there)

You can check desktop environment and session type by the command

```
env|grep XDG|grep -e XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP -e XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

Comment: So what's the solution? Or better use other?

Comment: @ßiansorÅ.Ålmerol, The OP switched to x11 (and reposrted that it works well enough),

Comment: Yeah I switched yesterday cause I can't find any solution it works thanks

Answer (score 2):

Switching from Wayland to x11 solved most of the problems (see @sudodus comments).

It is possible to pick a color with Gpick but the small box still does not show anything.

Pick seems to work fine although the display of the app is kind of buggy.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on GNOME 3.32 *with X11*

In my case, however, I had desktop zoom enabled. Disabling desktop zoom fixed the issue. You can do this via the accessibility icon in the top panel - or by using a keyboard shortcut - the default for turning zoom on or off is `Super+Alt+8`

Comment: What is the "accessibility icon"? On the bottom right of Gpick window, there is a pick colors icon. The default shortcut seems to be Ctrl+P. I note that this icon button works fine! It displays a desktop zoom box that follows the mouse. However, the pick color button on the top left of Gpick window still don't display the desktop zoom.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this you need to disable Wayland. To this, edit the following file:

```
nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment present line to/or set WaylandEnable to false as follows:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Save the file and reboot your machine (recommended), or  restart GDM3 with the command below:

```
systemctl restart gdm3
```